# Calculate percentage based on row_number in sql

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to write a sql query that for each returned row, will also return a percentage (0-100) based on its row position. To further complicate this, the query is also currently grouped. Here's some example data to play with:

```
create table #test(StockId int)
insert into #test values (101), (101), (202), (202), (303), (404), (505)

select 
StockId,
count(*) as BinMovements
from #test
group by StockId
order by BinMovements desc
```

This query currently returns:

> StockId, BinMovements
>   101, 2
>   202, 2
>   303, 1
>   404, 1
>   505, 1

(Though obviously, because BinMovements is either 2 or 1 it would be equally correct to return the StockIds in a different order such as):

> 202, 2
>   101, 2
>   404, 1
>   303, 1
>   505, 1

I'd like to add a 'percentage' column, but this is really just based on row position, so I'd like to see values like:

> 101, 2, 100
>   202, 2, 80
>   303, 1, 60
>   404, 1, 40
>   505, 1, 20

I imagine the solution may involve `ROW_NUMBER`, and I started down this path thinking I could just get ROW_NUMBER / total rows * 100, but this isn't working for some reason. Possibly because of the group by clause?

```
select 
StockId,
count(*) as BinMovements,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by (count(*))) as RowNumber,
count(*) over () as TotalCount,
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by (count(*)))) / (count(*) over ()) * 100 as Percentage
from #test
group by StockId
order by RowNumber desc
```

returns:

```
StockId BinMovements    RowNumber   TotalCount  Percentage
202     2               5           5           100
101     2               4           5           0
505     1               3           5           0
404     1               2           5           0
303     1               1           5           0
```

I'd prefer to do this in a single select if possible, though if not wrapping it in an outer select may be a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both COUNT and ROW_NUMBER functions returns BIGINT.
Therefore result of division is also converted to BIGINT.

This works (you should multiply before divide):

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by (count(*)))) * 100 / (count(*) over ()) as Percentage
```

Comment: This works (thanks!), but I'm still a little confused as to why my solution ROWNUMBER / ROWCOUNT * 100 didn't work, but ROWNUMBER * 100 / ROWCOUNT does.

Comment: (1/5) = 0.2, rounded to 0 (when implicit converted to BIGINT). 0 * 100 = 0.  (1 * 100 / 5) = 20, rounded to 20

Comment: Try simple example: `SELECT 2/3` (returns 0)

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using `count() over()` and `row_number()` similar to your question, just reordering equation.

Note that the `order by` for the `row_number()` is the inverse of the `order by` for the statement, because we want to start the percentage at 100. Otherwise you can end up with 80 as the first row, 100 as the second, etc.

```
select 
    StockId
  , BinMovements = count(*)
  , Percentage = 100/count(*) over () 
    * row_number() over (order by count(*) asc, stockid desc)
from #test
group by StockId
order by BinMovements desc, StockId asc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TCPE10348

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
| StockId | BinMovements | Percentage |
+---------+--------------+------------+
|     101 |            2 |        100 |
|     202 |            2 |         80 |
|     303 |            1 |         60 |
|     404 |            1 |         40 |
|     505 |            1 |         20 |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

If you want a decimal percentage, change `100` to `100.0` in the equation.

Comment: `Percentage = 100/count(*) over ()  * row_number() over (order by count(*) asc, stockid desc)` is incorrect if count() > 100

Comment: @MikhailLobanov It depends on how you want to round your numbers. http://rextester.com/SYXIJG79973